# Optional parameter in Javascript reduce function

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I'm working on writing a reduce function in Javascript. The function works correctly when no argument for start(the counter) is passed, but when a start value is passed, I get an incorrect answer. For example, if I pass      `([1,2,3], function(a,b){return a + b;}, 0)` to the function, it outputs 5 instead of 6. If no third argument(start value) is passed, I want the "total" variable to be set to the first element in the array using shift, so that element is then removed and not counted again.

```
function reduce(arr, func, start) {
    var total = start || arr.shift();
    each(arr, function(item) {
        total = func(item, total);
    });
    return total;
};
```

(Each is a simple forEach function I wrote, that works fine.) I've tried a ton of different variations, and I can't seem to get this to work. Is there a better way set the total variable when no third argument is passed?

Comment: You are trying to create a JS function that SUMS all elements in an array ?

Comment: Not neccessarily that sums, just one that reduces the elements in an array to one based on a passed function(func argument). It could multiply them or reduce in another way, I just used sum since it's easiest.

Comment: I run it and it returns 6 for me: http://jsfiddle.net/07hgjLcd/

Comment: It is working fine and give 6 whats the actuall issue?

Comment: Also, what happens if `start` is `0`? That will be considered "falsey" by JS, so it will use the first element in the array instead. That could be a nasty bug to find one day. The way [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-25) and [Lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.5.0/lodash.src.js#L6646) do it is to use `arguments.length < 3` as the condition instead.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited. It works fine if no third argument is passed, but when I pass one (0 in the example) it then returns 5 instead of 6.

Comment: @MattBass http://jsfiddle.net/07hgjLcd/1/ no id does not. Could you please assemble the complete runnable example that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I would not modifiy the original array, that's a rather undesirable side-effect in a reduce function.

Explicit is also better than implicit. You might want to use a falsy value for "start", after all.

```
function reduce(arr, func, start) {
    var total; i;
    if (typeof start === "undefined") {
        total = arr[0];
        i = 1;
    } else {
        total = start;
        i = 0;
    }
    for (; i < arr.length; i++) {
        total = func(arr[i], total);
    }
    return total;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

And just for fun, a recursive implementation (which will be optimized using TR optimization in ES6):

```
function reduce(arr, func, start) {
    if (arr.length == 0) {
        return start;
    }

    var accum = typeof start == 'undefined' ? arr[0] : func(start, arr[0]);

    return reduce(arr.slice(1), func, accum);
}

console.log(reduce([1,2,3], function(a,b){return a + b;}));
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k3kuoz3w/1/

**UPD**:

In the comments [@Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak) mentioned that this solution would create an array every iteration.

For even better fun here is a solution that does not create unnecessary copies:

```
function reduce(arr, func, start, i) {
    if (arr.length == i) {
        return start;
    }

    i = i || 0;

    var accum = typeof start == 'undefined' ? arr[i] : func(start, arr[i]);

    return reduce(arr, func, accum, i + 1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k3kuoz3w/2/

**UPD 2**:

the last solution (I promise) that encapsulates the dirty `i` exposed in the previous code:

```
function reduce(arr, func, start) {
    function real_reduce(arr, func, start, i) {
        if (arr.length == i) {
            return start;
        }

        var accum = typeof start == 'undefined' ? arr[i] : func(start, arr[i]);

        return real_reduce(arr, func, accum, i + 1);
    }

    return real_reduce(arr, func, start, 0)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k3kuoz3w/3/

Comment: The tail-recursive variant is nice. I would just avoid it because it needlessly creates new arrays with every step.

Comment: @Tomalak indeed. In a "better language" it would reuse the tail though.

Comment: Oh, you can do that in JavaScript, too. You just have to avoid slice. :)

Comment: @Tomalak to pass a structure with an array and index altogether?

Comment: Something like that. Or move the recursion to an inner function that takes the array and an index parameter.

Comment: @Tomalak it's an arrow up :-) Like - look there :-)

Comment: I'm a bit reluctant about exposing the `i` parameter in the outer function signature. That goes against the principle of reduce... that's why I spoke of an inner function.

Comment: Also it doesn't throws error when array contains no element,

Maximum call stack exceeded error come which is wrong and very inefficient

Comment: @WebServer it should not throw error actually when the array is empty. "Maximum call stack exceeded error come which is wrong and very inefficient" --- 1. it was done for "science" and fun 2. TR optimization will come in ES6 3. It's an implementation with functional programming paradigm kept in mind. In more "suitable" programming languages (haskell, clojure) the similar solution would perform and look much better (not to say it would look naturally)

Comment: @zerkms: write   [].reduce(function(a, b){return a + b})  in your console, and see it by yourself, what it should be :>

Comment: @WebServer it's a JS oddity. Traditionally reduce does not do that :-)

Comment: I get that point but since we are doing it in JavaScript its better to do it.

Comment: @WebServer I don't think so. When one reimplements a `reduce` function instead of using the one from the library they might prefer the more "traditional" behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

another simple recursive function

Newer:

```
function reduce(arr, fn, start) {
  if(typeof start !== "undefined") {
    return recur([start].concat(arr), 0);
  } else {
    return recur(arr,0)
  }
  function recur(arr, index) {
    if(arr.length === 0) {
      return RangeError();
    } else if(index + 1 === arr.length) {
      return arr[index];
    } else {
      return fn(arr[index] , recur(arr, index + 1));
    }
  }
}
console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3], function(a, b) {return a + b}))
console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3], function(a, b) {return a + b}, 9))
console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3], function(a, b) {return a + b}, 0))
console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3], function(a, b) {return a * b}, 1))
console.log(reduce([], function(a, b) {return a + b}, 0))
```

OLDER Comment(Don't refer this) :

reduce(arr, fn, start) {
  if(typeof start === undefined) {
    return reduce(arr, fn, 0)
  } else {
    var total = start;
    each(arr, function(item) {
        total = func(item, total);
    });
    return total;
  }
}

Comment: It's not correct to define `0` as an initial value. If reduction function is `*` then the identity value must be `1` for example. I actually wouldn't call it recursive as well, since the main job is still done in an explicit loop with a mutable state.

Comment: true agreed with you